# Advatanges of using prototype object to add custom properties and methods to a javascript object

Tags: javascript

What is the advantage of using prototype object for adding custom properties and methods against the usage of `this` property ?

For example, this code from http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto3.shtml

```
//First, create the custom object "circle"
function circle(){
}
circle.prototype.pi=3.14159

// create the object method
function alertmessage(){
alert(this.pi)
}
circle.prototype.alertpi=alertmessage
```

Isn't the above function same as

```
//First, create the custom object "circle"
function circle(){
   this.pi=3.14159; 
   this.alertmessage(){
      alert(this.pi)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign to `this.something` in the constructor, then each object has it's own copy of the object you define. So if you assign your member functions this way, you'll get lots of repeated function objects.

Prototypes let you share the function implementation across every instance. It also lets you do what are effectively class variables - state shared across all instances based on that prototype. It also opens up some more advanced sharing possibilities that nobody in practice actually uses.

Comment: Thats neat but does it not mean that if I use prototype then most of the constructors would be just empty functions ?

Comment: No, the constructor's used for initializing per-object state. You only put stuff that's shared across all objects created by that constructor in the prototype. I also recommend you read "Javascript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford for an excellent discussion of how this all works and why you may want to choose a particular approach here.

Comment: Thanks, downloaded the e-book